# How do I find the duplicate signal definition, if the synthesizer reports the wrong line number?

Tags: vhdl

I have a big pile of generated VHDL that I am passing to Xilinx ISE 14.7. During synthesis, eventually it fails with the following error message:

> Line 6134: Signal `inst_chip8/clash_explicit_mealy_mealy_cpuout/_` is defined more than once.

I'd like to understand what is causing this so I can either fix the generator or tweak the input source.

The problem is that there is **no filename in the error message and none of my files even has 6134 lines**. I've uploaded the full suite of VHDL files to [GitHub](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-issue-356); if I follow the instantiation route in the error message, it should point to the file [`clash_explicit_mealy_mealy.vhdl`](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-issue-356/blob/master/vhdl/CHIP8/CHIP8/clash_explicit_mealy_mealy.vhdl) which is only 3422 lines long.

Furthermore, **there doesn't appear to be a signal called `_` in that file**.

So given all these contradictions, **how do I find the location in the VHDL files of the duplicate signal definitions?**

Comment: @user1155120 yeah it seems CLaSH converts everything to 64-bit `Int`s for some reason, but as long as everything gets converted back to its original small width at its consumption, it shouldn't be a problem should it?

Comment: @user1155120: I can't try it out right now, but will give it a shot if it can help: are you saying the unguarded `block` statements don't make any semantic difference and just flattening their contents into the main `begin..end` scope would/could help?

Comment: I analyzed, elaborated and simulated CHIP8 using a rudimentary testbench providing 25 MHz clock and reset event, static '0's or '1's for other inputs. It produced a large number of metavalue warnings from package numeric_std indicating a lack of initial values and updates (to_integer warnings per clock) for signed and/or unsigned objects. Running the simulation for 200 us shows hsync. Your model likely doesn't have a VHDL problem (and is related to a synthesis tool as well as lacking a [mcve]). The error message provides no insight and may indicate running out of memory.

Comment: The simulation settled down to one metavalue report every 500 us or so after it started [displaying visible pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ixTL.jpg). The waveform dump (of every signal) is only about 150 MBytes. I'll get an execution time on my Macbook after it quits at 20 ms. Seems like it's still going through initialization.

Comment: Thank you so much for this analysis. I think the metavalue warnings are coming from not including a reset spike; there is a [top-level VHDL wrapper file in the repo](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-issue-356/blob/master/src-vhdl/Top.vhdl) that adds the reset. 

What simulator are you using?

Comment: So would it be a fair summary to say (and I would definitely accept this as an answer!) that the error comes from the synergy of two problems: 1, CLaSH generates horribly inefficient VHDL, and 2, the Xilinx ISE falls over on too complex VHDL? (since I don't believe it is actually running out of memory on my 24G machine)

Comment: Zipped through the last ms, must have gone idle. Over 2 1/2 hours real time (late 2008 2.4 GHz 8GB DDR3 Macbook doing other things). The [testbench](https://www.dropbox.com/s/irjr6adsl8tsmq5/chip8_tb.vhdl?dl=1) does a reset. [Makefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/viuttv74qgkpn8g/Makefile?dl=1). I used an assert to kill the clock at 20 ms. ghdl 0.36-dev v0.35-271-g5cd3de4 - the commit, 24 Aug, llvm backend) and gtkwave. Not a complex hardware design, hard to synthesize, slow to simulate, unnecessary intermediary signals, block statements.